# fastapi/uvicorn prevent ungzipping with httpx.AsyncClinet

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, httpx

i work on reverse proxy based on fastapi. I want transparenty send data requested by AsyncClient. I have problem with gziped pages. Please can you help me, how to prevent default ungzipping of resp.content on this example?

````
@app.get("/{path:path}")
async def _get ( path: str, request: Request ):
    url = await my_proxy_logic (path, request)
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        req = client.build_request("GET", url)
        resp = await client.send(req, stream=False)
    return Response( status_code=resp.status_code, headers=resp.headers, content=resp.content)```
````

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to extract undecoded data from `httpx` response only in case of streaming mode `stream=True` or `httpx.stream`. In the example below, I collect the entire response using [`aiter_raw`](https://www.python-httpx.org/api/#response) and return it from the path operation. Keep in mind that the entire response is loaded into memory, if you want to avoid this use fastapi [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=stream#streamingresponse)

```py
import httpx
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/pass")
async def root(request: Request):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        req = client.build_request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/gzip')
        resp = await client.send(req, stream=True)
        return Response(status_code=resp.status_code, headers=resp.headers,
                        content=b"".join([part async for part in resp.aiter_raw()]))
```