# How to forward FastAPI requests to another server?

Tags: python, rest, request, fastapi, forward

I have a FastAPI application for testing/development purposes. What I want is that any request that arrives to my app to automatically be sent, as is, to another app on another server, **with exactly the same parameters and same endpoint**. This is **not** a redirect, because I still want the app to process the request and return values as usual. I just want to initiate a similar request to a different version of the app on a different server, without waiting for the answer from the other server, so that the other app gets the request as if the original request was sent to it.

How can I achieve that? Below is a sample code that I use for handling the request:

```
@app.post("/my_endpoint/some_parameters")
def process_request(
    params: MyParamsClass,
    pwd: str = Depends(authenticate),
):
    # send the same request to http://my_other_url/my_endpoint/
    return_value = process_the_request(params)
    return return_value.as_json()
```

Comment: @AndrewRyan I'd like to connect via HTTP. do you mean something like this?

changing the header of my function to:
def process_request(params:MyParamsClass,pwd=,request:Request)

and then within my function:
requests.request("POST",my_url,request)

I'm not sure what the syntax should be

Comment: @AndrewRyan my apologies if this seems too basic. I know how to send a request, I'm not sure how to get the original request json and headers given that my function gets a param class which assumes some structure

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`AsyncClient()`](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#making-async-requests) from the [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) library, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73770074/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) (have a look at those answers for more details on the approach demonstrated below). You can spawn a `Client` inside the [`startup` event handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event), store it on the `app` instance—as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71298949/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613757/17865804)—and reuse it every time you need it. You can explicitly `close` the `Client` once you are done with it, using the [`shutdown` event handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#shutdown-event) (**Update:** Since `startup` and `shutdown` events are now deprecated and might be completely removed in the future, the example below has been updated based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), which demonstrates how to use a `lifespan` event handler instead).

### Working Example

##### The Main Server

When building the request that is about to be forwarded to the other server, the main server uses `request.stream()` to read the request `body` from the client's request, which provides an `async` iterator, so that if the client sent a request with some large body (for instance, the client uploads a large file), the main server would not have to wait for the entire `body` to be received and loaded into memory before forwarding the request, something that would happen in case you used `await request.body()` instead, which would likely cause server issues, if the entire request `body` could not fit into the server's RAM.

You could add multiple routes in the same way the `/upload` one has been defined below, specifying the path, as well as the HTTP method for the endpoint. Note that the `/upload` route below uses Starlette's `path` convertor to capture arbitrary paths, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295133/17865804). You could also specify the exact path parameters, if you wish, but the example below provides a more convenient way, if there were multiple path parameters. Regardless, the path will be evaluated against the endpoint in the other server to which the request should be forwarded (demonstrated below), where you could explicitly specify the path parameters.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import httpx


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    # http://127.0.0.1:8001/ is the base_url of the other server that requests should be forwarded to
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(base_url='http://127.0.0.1:8001/') as client:
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown 


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


async def _reverse_proxy(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client
    url = httpx.URL(path=request.url.path, query=request.url.query.encode('utf-8'))
    req = client.build_request(
        request.method, url, headers=request.headers.raw, content=request.stream()
    )
    r = await client.send(req, stream=True)
    return StreamingResponse(
        r.aiter_raw(),
        status_code=r.status_code,
        headers=r.headers,
        background=BackgroundTask(r.aclose)
    )


app.add_route('/upload/{path:path}', _reverse_proxy, ['POST'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

##### The Other Server

Again, for the simplicity of this example, the `Request` object is used to read the requet body, but you could isntead define `UploadFile`, `Form`, Pydantic models and other parameters/dependencies as usual, which would be useful for validation purposes as well (see related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804)). In the example below, the server is listenning on port `8001`.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request


app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/upload/{p1}/{p2}')
async def upload(p1: str, p2: str, q1: str, request: Request):
    body = await request.body()
    print(f'p1: {p1}, p2: {p2}, q1: {q1}\nbody: {body}\n')
    return 'OK'
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8001)
```

##### Test the above example using `httpx`

```py
import httpx

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/hello/world'
params = {'q1': 'This is a query param'}

# send a multipart/form-data encoded request
files = {'file': open('file.txt', 'rb')}
r = httpx.post(url, params=params, files=files)
print(r.content)

# send an application/json encoded request
payload = {'msg': 'This is JSON data'}
r = httpx.post(url, params=params, json=payload)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: when forwarding the http request to the other server you probably shouldn't set the original `host` header, as the receiving server will most of the time not accept this. So instead of `headers=request.headers.raw` one could write `headers=[(key, value) for key, value in request.headers.raw if key != b'host']`