# How to map flower port 5556 to an enpoint in FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, celery, fastapi, flower

I have a simple FastAPI app. I am using celery for async task processing and flower dashboard for monitoring tasks

My main application is running on port **80**

My flower dashboard for task monitoring is running on port **5556**

Now I want to map the port to the app endpoint, something like - **http://localhost/flower-dashboard**

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  web:
    build: ./project
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://:password@redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://:password@redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    build: ./project
    command: celery worker --app=worker.celery --loglevel=info --logfile=logs/celery.log
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://:password@redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://:password@redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis

  redis:
    image: public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/redis:5.0-20.04_edge
    restart: always
    command: /bin/sh -c "redis-server --requirepass $$REDIS_HOST_PASSWORD"
    env_file:
      - redis.env
  dashboard:
    build: ./project
    command:  flower --app=worker.celery --port=5555 --broker=redis://:password@redis:6379/0
    ports:
      - 5556:5555
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://:password@redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://:password@redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You want dashboard `localhost:5556` to be accessible at `localhost/flower-dashboard`?

Comment: @Anton yes, precisely!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forward FastAPI requests to another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74555102/how-to-forward-fastapi-requests-to-another-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an easy thing to do. To map `localhost:5556` to `localhost/flower-dashboard` you'd need to use a proxy. You could add an Nginx or Apache service to your docker-compose configuration and make it route `localhost/flower-dashboard` requests to the `dashboard` service and all other requests `localhost/*` to the `web` service. This implies that you do not map `web` port 80 to the host like you do now, and map the proxy port 80 instead.