# Why is the client receiving a different status_code than the sent one?

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, http-status-codes, starlette

I have this endpoint in my API which calls another endpoint in another API. I'm just returning the received response to the client, but sometimes the client is actually receiving a different `status_code` than the one I'm passing in the `return` statement.

I'm doing it something like this (using FastAPI):

```py
@router.post("/my_endpoint")
async def my_method():
    ...
    response = requests.post(url=<url_to_the_other_api>, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    return response.json()
```

The client is sometimes receiving an error message but still with `status_code` 200. I thought I was returning the same received response object, but apparently not.

May someone please explain it?

I thought `json()` method or FastAPI could be creating a new `response` object and just using the old body. Is that what happens? This behavior is quite unclear to me.

Comment: You're just returning the JSON content, not the response code.

Comment: @Barmar oh... got it! That means the first request is succeded, and the client is receiving only the content of the second request. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `return response.json()` you are just returning the content of the `response` that you are getting from the request issued using Python `requests` to `<the_other_api>`. FastAPI, behind the scenes, will then put the JSON data into a `JSONResponse` and reuturn it back to the client using a `status_code` value of `200` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details).

If you would like to use the `status_code` (as well as the `media_type`/`content-type`) returned in the response from `<the_other_api>`, you could then [return a custom Response directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response).

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
import requests

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def root():
    # returns 400 Error Not Found Response (for testing purposes)
    #r = requests.get(url='http://httpbin.org/NotValidRoute')
    
    # reurns 200 Successful Response
    r = requests.get(url='http://httpbin.org/json')
    
    return Response(content=r.content, media_type=r.headers['content-type'], status_code=r.status_code)
```

I would, however, **strongly recommend** using the [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) library instead of `requests` (`httpx` has very similar syntax to `requests`, is easy to use and provides `async` support), as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804). If you would rather keep using `requests`, please make sure to define the endpoint with normal `def` (as shown in the exmaple above) **not** `async def` (as shown in your question)—have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details as to why.