# How to upload a file from FastAPI application to a Facebook Page using Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, fastapi, starlette

When I try to upload a video file to a Facebook page using the Graph API in python with this function:

```py
def upload_video_file(page_id: str, access_token: str, video_file: UploadFile):
    upload_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/videos"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    files = {"file": video_file.file}
    response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, files=files)
    data = response.json()
    if data:
        return data
    else:
        return {"message": "failed uploud video"}
```

and execute the above function from within the following FastAPI endpoint:

```py
@router.post("/upload-video/{page_id}")
async def post_video(page_id: str, video_file: UploadFile = File(...), access_token: str = Header(..., description="Access Token")):
    response = upload_video_file(page_id, access_token, video_file)
    return JSONResponse (response)pe here
```

I get this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 352,
    "error_subcode": 1363024,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Format Video Tidak Didukung",
    "error_user_msg": "Format video yang Anda coba unggah tidak didukung. Silakan coba lagi dengan sebuah video dalam format yang didukung.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AZNNyQhyPDfi5AhDOBpdA5c"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only website. Please [edit] the question and translate the error messages into English.

Comment: @Squarish `error.message` contains the same information in English as `error.error_user_msg`.

Comment: @DimasSurya The message "The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support." probably answers your question. Have you tried with different formats? What format are you using?

Comment: @joanis i try with mp4 video format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused due to sending binary data, using the `SpooledTemporaryFile` object that Starlette's `UploadFile` object uses under the hood—please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) for more details and examples—without specifying a `filename` and/or `content-type`.

Hence, the solution would be to specify those two attributes when defining the `files` variable before sending the HTTP request. You can find the relevant `requests` documentation [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) (see the `files` argument). You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) helpful as well. Example:

```py
files = {'file': ('video.mp4', video_file.file, 'video/mp4')}
```

or, if you would like to use the ones that come with the file uploaded by the user, you could instead use the below (make sure they are not `None`):

```py
files = {'file': (video_file.filename, video_file.file,  video_file.content_type)}
```

On a side note, I would not suggest using the `requests` library for performing HTTP requests in an `async` environment such as FastAPI's. If you would still like to use `requests`, you should at least drop the `async` definition from your endpoint, which would result in FastAPI running that endpoint in an external threadpool that would be then `await`ed, in order to prevent the endpoing from blocking the event loop (and hence, the entire server). Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for a thorough explanation, details and examples around `async def` and normal `def` in FastAPI.

Alternatively, you could use the [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) library, which provides an [`async` API](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) as well, and has very similar syntax to `requests`. Details and examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804). The relevant documentation on how to explicitly set the `filename` and `content-type` for `files`, can be found [here](https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#sending-multipart-file-uploads). Not only that, you could [initialise a global `Client` object at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and reuse it accross the application, instead of creating a new `Client` session every time a request arrives to that endpoint. Finally, you could also return a custom `JSONResponse` to the user when the file failed to upload for some reason, by specifying a custom response `status_code`—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, File, UploadFile, Header, status
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import httpx


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown 


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.post('/upload-video/{page_id}')
async def upload_video(
    request: Request,
    page_id: str,
    file: UploadFile = File(...),
    access_token: str = Header(...),
):
    client = request.state.client
    url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/videos'
    files = {'file': (file.filename, file.file, file.content_type)}
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    req = client.build_request(method='POST', url=url, files=files, headers=headers)
    r = await client.send(req)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()
    else:
        return JSONResponse(
            content='File failed to upload',
            status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        )
```