# FaceBook Graph API responds with "Provide valid app ID" error when sending an HTTP request

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, fastapi, facebook-page

In the documentation it is not told to include `page_id` in the request but this error says to `provide a valid application id`:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Provide valid app ID",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AA23cGCw0PM8uPLrX2SdyhS"
  }
}
```

I want to see which apps have installed Pages in webhook meta with this function

```py
def cek_subs_app_webhook(page_id, access_token):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/subscribed_apps"
    payload = {
        'access_token': access_token
    }
    get = requests.get(url, data= payload)
    return get.json()
```

and execute the function with this FastAPI app

```py
@router.get("/cek-subs-app/{page_id}")
async def check(page_id: str, access_token: str = Header(..., description="meta token")):
    response = cek_subs_app_webhook(page_id, access_token)
    return JSONResponse (response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `access_token` as a `Form` parameter, when using the `data` argument in Python `requests`. If you would like to add the `access_token` to the query string instead (i.e., as a query parameter), you should use the `params` argument.  Example:

```py
q_params= {'access_token': access_token}
r = requests.get(url, params=q_params)
```

Alternatively, you could add the `access_token` to the `headers`, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76437623/17865804).

I would highly recommend using `httpx` instead of `requests`; especially, if you are going to define the endpoint with `async def`. Please have at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) for more details and examples.