# async httpx requests fails when using redis cache backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, fastapi, httpx

I'm running a FastAPI that makes some external calls to fetch data and it use the cache decorator to store the auth tokens; The app works with in-memory and Redis Backend (usually in-memory for local dev, but I tried to test the code for both backends)

Now, recently I'm moving from sync calls to async calls; I mean, from `requests` to `httpx` but I did notice the `httpx` calls fails when I use redis as cache Backend but works properly when in-memory.

Any ideas to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) helpful

Comment: Thanks Chris, I really found pretty tricky to explain this issue as it seems not correlated and even was afraid to posted it here.
Basically the steps to reproduce it is: 

A `FastAPI` application + Having a connection to `Redis` + Whatever async call (`httpx.AsyncClient().request(...)` in my case)

I found the solution here https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/2633.

updating to python 3.11.4 solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution under this thread https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/2633

Update to python 3.11.4 would solve the problem